# Error of properties

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors

I am here after 4 or more days of investigation about the same error. I have created a project using JHipster written in angular and I want to test it. JHipster generates by default some beginner testing code.

I follow this tutorial [enter link description here](https://www.jhipster.tech/running-tests/) to run the tests but something seems to be wrong and some errors appear.

What have I done:

Install all of the karma plugins.
Install tslint, karma, jasmine, typscript
I enter in the src\test\javascript\spec I use the command **yarn test** The error that appears is this:

```html
ERROR: C:/Users/67563478/new_workspace/onconsup/src/main/webapp/app/entities/qu
mioterapia/quimioterapia-dialog.component.ts[31, 17]: Property 'activatedRoute'
is declared but its value is never read.
ERROR: C:/Users/67563478/new_workspace/onconsup/src/main/webapp/app/entities/ra
ioterapia/radioterapia-dialog.component.ts[31, 17]: Property 'activatedRoute' i
 declared but its value is never read.
ERROR: C:/Users/67563478/new_workspace/onconsup/src/main/webapp/app/entities/ot
o-tratamiento/otro-tratamiento-dialog.component.ts[33, 17]: Property 'activated
oute' is declared but its value is never read.
ERROR: C:/Users/67563478/new_workspace/onconsup/src/main/webapp/app/entities/fa
maco/farmaco-dialog.component.ts[9, 19]: 'Unidad' is declared but its value is
ever read.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! oncosup@0.0.0 lint: `tslint --project tsconfig.json -e 'node_modules/*
'`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oncosup@0.0.0 lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional lo
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\67563478\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-11T08_51
27_128Z-debug.log
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 2
Command: C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe
Arguments: /d /s /c npm run lint && karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.
s
Directory: C:\\Users\\67563478\
ew_workspace\\onconsup
Output:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information
rovided in "C:\\Users\\67563478\
ew_workspace\\onconsup\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this com
and.
```

If I remove them the app doesnt work, and if I make them public or levae them without public/private the error is something else (look in tis question).[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980661/tslint-and-node-modules-errorrs)

I cannot run the tests this way, nor with karma nor with cucumber. It is the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you have initialized in constructor, `activatedRoute` but its never been used anywhere.

This is why, typescript is giving you error. Remove unused things to fix the warning

Comment: Yeah, true but this property is being used in other classes that import this one, cause this is how angular works.So, if I remove it I will have other errors

Comment: If it is not getting used in this class, then remove from this class and import in the other classes which use it